# How can I use the parameter that is stored in class in array

Tags: python, list, class, mlp

I have a question about my code.
It is about the layer in MLP.
I set the layers in list with class, such that

```
class Linear:
    def __init__(self, n, m, i = Flase):
        context
class ReLU:
    def __init__(self)
        context
```

And in other class I append the class in List

```
class MLP:
    def __init__(self, features):
        for i, (n, m) in context):
            layers += [Linear(n, m, i==0), ReLU()]
        return layers
```

Then I try to use the layer in "layers" list in other class, so how can I use the parameter I stored before.
(Exactly in "n" and "m" in Linear class)
I write the code that

```
for i in range(len(layers)):
    if isinstance(layers[i], Linear):
```

And Next line I want to use the parameter in Liner class which is "n" and "m".
Is their any solution with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I was able to understand of your question, you want to assign some attributes to a class instance in it's constructor and then you want to be able to access those attributes afterwards.

Here is an example of how you might do that.

```
class Linear:
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n   # make instance attributes using self
        self.m = m


layers = []

for (n, m) in context:  
    layers += [Linear(n, m)]


for i in range(len(layers)):
    if isinstance(layers[i], Linear):
        var = layers[i]
        print(var.n)  
        print(var.m) # <--- use the obj.attr syntax to get the attributes
```